# Identify IE8 and IE9 in java script function

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-browser

How to identify the running Internet Explorer Versions which is IE7,IE8 or IE9. According to this, I need to call the css styles using the java script function. Please write that javascript code.

Help me

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: I assume you're doing this to determine if the browser has support for various features. It's better to detect the existence of the features, rather than the browser itself: http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Why do you need to do it in javascript? Is this an assignment or are you actually trying to solve a real-world problem? If so, what is *that* actual problem? The right way to handle CSS in IE is not with javascript.

Comment: I want to identify the IE browser Version which is IE8 or IE9 to call the css file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

If your objective is purely to include specific stylesheets for specific versions of Internet Explorer, you want to use conditional includes:

**HTML**

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8.css">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css">
<![endif]-->
```

And so on.

Answer (score 0):

Usually detecting features is the best thing, but a fairly good point in this special case is detecting the existence of conditional comments, which are supported by IE only.

Here's what I usually do:

```
var div = document.createElement("div"), IE;
div.innerHTML = "<!--[if IE 5]>5<![endif]--><!--[if IE 5.0]>5.0<![endif]--><!--[if IE 5.5]>5.5<![endif]-->\
    <!--[if IE 6]>6<![endif]--><!--[if IE 7]>7<![endif]--><!--[if IE 8]>8<![endif]--><!--[if IE 9]>9<![endif]-->";
IE = d.firstChild && d.firstChild.nodeType===3 ? +d.innerHTML : false;
```